# SQL Server 2008/SSIS: Guid has brackets after being written to a text file

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, text-files

```
SELECT
    Id AS VEHICLE_GUID
FROM
    Vehicles WITH(NOLOCK)
```

Result should be:  `2343-GUID-EX-AMPLE`

But instead is: `[2343-GUID-EX-AMPLE]`

This is a truly simple query, I am using sql-server-2008 and BIDS (SSIS).  When I preview the result, there is no brackets.

However, when I execute the task that runs the query and writes the results to the text file, when i go to open the text file i see brackets around the GUIDS.  I am frustrated because I do not see a property on the text file destination that would cause this....Or maybe I am overlooking something? Maybe this can be solved from query?

Any thought would be greatly appreciated and attempted.  I have no more hair to pull out.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: this is not what SQL execution produce, this is happening in your application layer, check to see if that is format done by the way you write to the file

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a function of the datatype you are using.  You should be able to cast/convert it as varchar and avoid the problem, or at least then run functions against it to strip out the brackets.

Comment: running a function would work, but the brackets only appear after they are written to the text file

Comment: Try doing the cast/convert then and see if that causes the brackets to appear in the return results or prevents them from appearing in the text file.